# Why can I not guess the correct number in this random number guesser in python 3.8.2?

Tags: python, random

```
import random

num=int(input("What is the highest number you want? "))

r=random.randint(0,num)

answer=int(input("Guess the number! "))

if answer!= r:
  if answer < r:
    print("More!")
    
  if answer > r:
    print("Less!")
  
  if answer==r:
    print("Correct!")
    quit()

  if answer !=r:
    answer = int(input('Second guess out of 3! '))

    if answer != r:
      if answer < r:
        print('Lower!')

      if answer > r:
        print('Higher!')

      if answer == r:
        print('Correct!')
        quit()

      answer = int(input('Final guess! '))

      if answer == r:
        print('Finally!')
        quit()
      else:
        print('Damn... you lost.')
        quit()
```

My limit was 5, and it said it was between 3 and 4.
I guessed 3 and it said it was too low.
I guessed 4 and it said it was too high.
Please help!
It may be the variables or possibly my limited understanding of the random module.

Am relatively new to programming so much explanation would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can never reach your "Correct" condition:

```
if answer!= r:
  
  # etc

  if answer==r:
    print("Correct!")
    quit()
```

It's not possible for `answer == r` to be true inside a block that's already conditional on `answer != r`.

What you probably want to do is check for `answer == r` immediately so you can `quit()` on a correct answer and otherwise continue.  That way you don't even need to explicitly check for `answer != r`, which makes the code simpler by removing a lot of extra indentation:

```
import random

num = int(input("What is the highest number you want? "))

r = random.randint(0,num)

answer = int(input("Guess the number! "))
if answer == r:
    print("Correct!")
    quit()

if answer < r:
    print("More!")
if answer > r:
    print("Less!")

answer = int(input('Second guess out of 3! '))
if answer == r:
    print('Correct!')
    quit()

if answer < r:
    print('Lower!')
if answer > r:
    print('Higher!')

answer = int(input('Final guess! '))
if answer == r:
    print('Finally!')
    quit()

print('Damn... you lost.')
```

The problem you might be running into when you actually play your game is that you're using different words to indicate a wrong guess:

```
if answer < r:
    print("More!")
if answer > r:
    print("Less!")

# etc

if answer < r:
    print('Lower!')
if answer > r:
    print('Higher!')
```

In one case you're saying that the *answer* is more than the *guess*, and in the other you're saying that the *guess* is lower than the *answer*, and in both case you're meaning the same thing but saying something entirely different.  (This is also made more confusing when reading the code because the answer is `r` and the guess is `answer` -- I had to reread it a few times when writing the above sentence to make sure I had it straight in my own head.)  Maybe that's intentionally confusing to make the game harder, but if not you probably want to clarify the wording of your clues, or use the same wording both times.

Comment: You'll notice that now the program is basically the same thing copied and pasted three times with minor variations -- once you learn about loops you'll be able to make your code repeat things without having to actually repeat your code.  :)

Comment: and it also seems to me that instead of `quit()` it is better to use `break`, am I right?

Comment: If it's in a loop, yes!  If it were in a function you could also `return`.  If all the code is at the top level (like it is in this script) then `quit()` or `exit()` is the only way to break the control flow without raising an exception.

Comment: oh yes, I forgot that unfortunately the loop is not used here, which you actually noticed, sorry for my inattention.

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks for the detail given into why the problem happened